How to determine the printf format specifier of a type at compile time?
Other methods of formatting are not a solution to the general problem. A printf format string is required.
It feels like there should be a simple way to get this function as a macro or constexpr:
int -> "d"
unsigned -> "u"
long -> "ld"
unsigned long -> "lu"
long long -> "lld"
unsigned long long -> "llu"

For use in portable code like:
std::chrono::milliseconds value{20};
char buffer[128];
std::snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "...%" FMT(std::chrono::milliseconds::rep) "...", value.rep());

Is there something in C++20† or maybe Boost that can do that?

†While the toolchains I have available support -std=c++20, they do not have std::format available. Moreover, there are C libraries that require printf format strings as arguments.

If you are using modern C++, why do you need printf family at all ? Why not use streams (like stringstream in this case), or std::format ?

You could implement it yourself, but I don't think I've seen existing implementations. Why not use std::format or fmt::format instead?

C++23 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print (std::print) does what you need

please specify C++xxx (standard) then

can you use https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt?

@wohlstad because I also need to call functions in a C library that take printf format stings.

@OrangeDog you can implement a set of overloads that accepts values, not types, and return the format string. Then use it with the actual values you pass to snprintf. The downside is that you will not be able to use compile time string concatenation.

Or implement something like std::numeric_limits<T> which will also let you get the format string as a constexpr I believe.

Also, snprintf has better performance than ostringstream and format in cases where that matters.

From the first glance, the link doesn't mention format.

@HolyBlackCat the linked benchmarks include boost::format, which I understand to be largely the same as std::format.

Don't conflate them, take a look here: https://github.com/fmtlib/format-benchmark fmt::format seems to outperform boost::format by quite a lot.

Please provide more details about Moreover, there are C libraries that require printf format strings as arguments.. What library is it,? Does that library use va_args or just only format string and ...? Does API use some compiler specific decorators? Which compilers you are using? Did you try tweak compiler warnings about format string (if yes why it didn't work?

@MarekR none of that is relevant to answering the question. The answers should be useful to as many people as possible.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Wouldn't a handful of manually overloaded constexpr functions do, possibly with a template catch-all that throws?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica that has been given as an answer

@OrangeDog Maybe we don't talk about the same thing; I cannot see such an answer. I'd simply say constexpr const char* fmt(char) { return "%c"; } constexpr const char* fmt(short) { return "%hd"; } constexpr const char* fmt(int) { return "%d"; }  etc.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica the parameter for that is a value, not a type.

@OrangeDog Yes. (I'm almost sure you are implying that that is not satisfactory -- can you elaborate on that? You'd use it like printf(fmt(val), (val)).) If you don't want to evaluate valtwice you can make that an inline function or lambda. (I'd also expect that optimization eliminates the useless expression, unless it has side effects.)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica that's not doing it at compile time

@OrangeDog Well, I was a bit confused: It is frigging constexpr; the compiler simply inserts an immediate value. Nothing is evaluated at all. OK, that's also not true; it is an immediate value and the expression is evaluated if it's not trivial.

@OrangeDog If you can mark a called function pure, it is not actually called: In [[gnu::pure]]const char x(); constexpr const char* fmt(char) { return "%c"; } char f() {     return *fmt(x()); }, f simply returns 37. Contrasting with a non-pure call: https://godbolt.org/z/css37EKj8

I'd prefer std::format or fmt::format, but this is how you can construct the format string for printf at compile-time:
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

template <std::size_t N>
struct ConstString
{
    char str[N]{};

    static constexpr std::size_t size = N - 1;

    constexpr ConstString() {}
    constexpr ConstString(const char (&new_str)[N])
    {
        std::copy_n(new_str, N, str);
    }

    constexpr operator const char *() const
    {
        return str;
    }
};

template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr ConstString<A + B - 1> operator+(const ConstString<A> &a, const ConstString<B> &b)
{
    ConstString<A + B - 1> ret;
    std::copy_n(a.str, a.size, ret.str);
    std::copy_n(b.str, b.size, ret.str + a.size);
    return ret;
}

template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr ConstString<A + B - 1> operator+(const ConstString<A> &a, const char (&b)[B])
{
    return a + ConstString<B>(b);
}

template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr ConstString<A + B - 1> operator+(const char (&a)[A], const ConstString<B> &b)
{
    return ConstString<A>(a) + b;
}

template <typename T>
struct PrintfPlaceholder {};
template <>
struct PrintfPlaceholder<int> {static constexpr ConstString value = "%d";};

Then:
int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    std::printf("x = " + PrintfPlaceholder<decltype(x)>::value, x);
}

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fehevTvnz

I assume you mean to include the other five specialisations at the end there? Everything else is just implementing constant strings?

@OrangeDog Yes, adding specializations is left as an exercise to the reader. "Everything else is just implementing constant strings?" What do you mean?

all the ConstString stuff. I was just confirming it doesn't magically generate the other cases through some obscure template voodoo.

You could make FMT do the whole conversion:
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

template<class... Args>
std::string FMT(Args&&... args) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    ((os << std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    return os.str();
}

...and then pass the result to the C function that requires snprintf arguments:
int main() {
    std::chrono::milliseconds value{20};
    char buffer[128];
    c_function_taking_snprintf_args(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s",
                                    FMT("Duration: ", value).c_str());
}

Alternatively, use the fmt library, which is supposed to have very good performance:
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

int main() {
    std::chrono::milliseconds value{20};
    char buffer[128];
    c_function_taking_snprintf_args(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s",
                                    fmt::format("Duration: {}", value).c_str());
}


One way to side-step the problem is to not use type-specific formatting, but use the largest possible integer type:
#include <cstdint>
//...
std::chrono::milliseconds value{20};
char buffer[128];
std::snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "...%" PRIiMAX  "...",
              std::intmax_t(value.count()));


Nice idea; one disadvantage will be a speed penalty though.
